# Why I cannot directly use for-each loop for generic type list?

Tags: java, foreach, generic-list, generic-type-argument

I am trying to do a for-each loop to get each element of a generic type List.

so if I first get the result, and do for-each loop, it will be fine.

```
List<MyClass<Entity>> res = response.getResponses();
MyClass<Entity> entity = res.get(0);

for(MyClass<Entity> a : res){
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

But if I want to direct fo the for-each loop, the IDE will complain that "Incompatible class. Required Object, Found  MyClass"

```
for(MyClass<Entity> a : response.getResponses()){
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

And I cannot use T as some posts elsewhere suggest. The IDE would show "Cannot resolve symbol 'T'"

```
for(MyClass<T> a : response.getResponses()){
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

EDIT:
Following is response class definition

```
public class Response<T> {
    private List<MyClass<T>> responses;

    public Response(List<MyClass<T>> responses) {
        this.responses = responses;
    }

    public List<MyClass<T>> getResponses() {
        return this.responses;
    }
}
```

And the returned type is actually an API call, I debugged and found out it should be of an Entity type.

Any idea about why?

Comment: Can you show the complete method definition of `response.getResponses()`, as well as the delcaration of  `response`? --- "*The IDE would show "Cannot resolve symbol 'T'"*"  - In order to use `T`, you need to define `T`, either on the class or on the method. If you do not want to or cannot define a `T`, use `?` (possibly with a wildcard).

Comment: In your second example, is the error about that specific line? Assuming no other code ws exchanged, the first and second ones should be equivelent

Comment: you need to declare T first in your generic method, public static <T> List<MyClass<Entity>>

Comment: @MatthewKerian yes, there would be a red underline about "MyClass<Entity> a"

Comment: What's the return type of response.getResponses()?

Comment: Where is Response instantiated? Generic type T doesn't extend anything, so the compiler can't tell what type it's supposed to be so it defaults to Object.

Comment: @MatthewKerian thanks so much! That's exactly the problem. I did it as ```Response response = theApiCall.getResponse;``` I thought that's irrelevant before....

Comment: ... then show the declaration of `theApiCall`, as well as the definition of `getResponse` within that class please.

Comment: You should show MyClass, Entity, and any other class you have.  Show the minimal required code to provide a complete compileable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give a personal answer to solve it without seeing more of your code base, but the actual issue is apparent.

Response is a class with a generic type. https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics

Reading that article before proceeding, it's generally good info to have in java, and the rest of this answer won't make sense without it.

T doesn't extend anything, so by default it extends Object. That's why if you do `ArrayList myList` it's equivalent to `ArrayList<Object> myList`. If you can change Response, you can update the generic to be `<T extends Entity>` and it'll work. That's assuming that every generic object T is going to be some sort of entity object.

The problem is at some point in your program you're losing the specifics on what the object is, consider this.

```
Response r = new Response();
List<Response<Entity>> list = r.getResponses();
```

The problem with that code is you're expecting a Response, but since type was never specified it defaults to `Response<Object> r = new Response()`. and while it may technically be returning Response under the hood, the compiler doesn't know that for sure.